# JavaScript hoisting for function expression and function declaration

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

I am learning hoisting in JavaScript and practicing some examples.

In an example I am confused of it's output.
Here is the example code:

```
var f = function(){
  console.log("Expression");
}
function f(){
  console.log("Declaration");
}
f();
```

The output of this code is **Expression**.
I was expecting the output would be **Declaration**.
If I write the code in this way:

```
function f(){
  console.log("Declaration");
}
var f = function(){
  console.log("Expression");
}
f();
```

The output remains **same**. 
How the output of this code is **Expression** ?

Comment: Function declarations are processed before any variable *assignment* (in the same scope of course), no matter where the are located in the source code. Therefore an assignment would always overwrite a declaration with the same name.

Comment: https://javascript.info/function-expressions#function-expression-vs-function-declaration

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, *function declarations* are hoisted, *variables* are not.

Because of that, in your first example the declaration is hoisted and then overridden.

Same thing happens in your second example.

Comment: I'd phrase this slightly differently. The key point is that although variable *declarations* (with `var`) are hoisted, *assignments* are not - even if the assignment happens in the same statement as the declaration (as `var f = "something";`). Whereas with a function declaration, the entire declaration - including the assignment of the function value to the variable - is hoisted. (I realise you almost certainly understand this, I'm just trying to clarify for the OP's benefit.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Absolutely right, and thanks for your additional clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

During initialization, the variable 'f' is assigned the function (Declaration).
Initialization happens before code is executed.
When the code is executed, the variable 'f' is assigned a new value (Expression)
That is, the function declaration will happen before you execute the code, regardless of where in the code the function is declared.